# My phone keeps getting disconnected from the wifi

Tags: router

Everytime I connect my phone to my wifi after a while it disconnects and won't work until I put the password again, reboot the router, or link the device via WPS. I'm desperate I can't even use my own wifi. You people seems the most reliable since every answer I got didn't work, so if the question doesn't belong here please just help me out and I will delete it.

Comment: What is the model of your router? What android is the model of your android device?

Comment: @narzard my phone is a Samsung s6, coded sm-g920f. My router is called "Tim ag combo"

Comment: @LPChip i Think the problem is in my router since today all other devices had an authentication error at the same time and I did another reebot, and they all connected back with no other issues. But my phone keeps getting disconnected, and it's been two days.

Comment: The question is, if you don't use wifi from your phone, but keep using it from your other devices, does the wifi crash too? If not and the phone is the source, we can't help you.

Comment: The wifi doesn't crash. It just stops working for me (but not for the other devices). After it gives me the error, it won't connect again until I reebot the modem or one of the thing I wrote in the question. Since the same thing happened to various devices I think it's an issue of the modem.  my father is having the same problems as I do now, he has an iphone and I have a android.

Comment: First thing to try is to assure the wireless encryption settings are WPA2-AES. Mixed modes like WPA/WPA2 and especially TKIP are known for having issues with certain device drivers, and any expert can tell you WPA2-AES is currently the only acceptable configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reputable ethernet router (one which can run DD-WRT is a good bet), and connect the WAN interface from your Tim AG combo to it.   You may also need to change the LAN subnet on one of the devices to a different range so as not to have conflict).  Disable WIFI on the Tim AG combo if you can.

Your problem is most probably a combination of compatibility issues between devices - new routers, and routers with a greater number of users typically iron out most of these problems.   (I could be doing it a disservice, but my guess is your provider has rebranded a cheap-as modem/router to keep their prices down, and you are paying the cost - I could not find ANY English references to it, and the pictures don't inspire confidence of a well made product designed for WIFI - for example no decent external aerials)

Otherwise complain to your ISP that there router is not doing the job you are paying for !